# Ruby on Rails (5.2.0.beta2) initializers loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to make own initializer for custom lib, and I have made it in exactly same maner as it's done in knock gem, here's the module:

https://github.com/nsarno/knock/blob/master/lib/knock.rb

And here's initializer:
https://github.com/nsarno/knock/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/knock.rb

So my code is totally same, but with different module name & attribute names.
**But** there is a difference in how it works. Anytime I run `rails c`, custom value for `Knock.token_lifetime` set in knock initializer is correct, but the same is not always correct for my own module, sometimes it's `nil` and sometimes it's the value set in initializer.
Here's the code in `lib/my_module.rb`

```
module MyModule
  mattr_accessor :some_attr
  self.some_attr = nil

  # Default way to setup MyModule.
  def self.setup
    yield self
  end
end
```

And here's the code in `config/initializers/my_module.rb`

```
MyModule.setup do |config|
  config.some_attr = 'some_val'
end
```

I have noticed that when I change some code inside my_module initializer and run `rails c` - everything is fine, but when I change some other file and run `rails c` - `MyModule.some_attr` is `nil`.
Also, I think that Knock also is a rails engine (I'm not sure, I've never tried to create my own engine), but I do not know if that somehow affects how module initializer works.

My question is: does someone knows why does my own module behaves strange with `rails c`, while Knock is totally OK, and how can I make my own module work as expected.